# Is there a way to spawn a new process without terminating the other threads?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, exec

I'm writing the multithreaded program on Linux and want to create a process in a thread without ending the other threads. I looked into fork/exec but in the exec man page in section 3p on linux states:

```
 A call to any exec function from a process with more  than  one  thread
 shall  result  in  all  threads being terminated and the new executable
 image being loaded and  executed.  No  destructor  functions  shall  be
 called.
```

Is there a way to spawn a new process without terminating the other threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But if you fork() first and exec in the child, the child process only has one thread and that is destroyed by the exec function. The parent process and all of its threads are unaffected.